# Jquery gives error in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I've got this script on my website for sharing on facebook/twitter etc...

It works in IE firefox , but not in chrome.

Script looks like this:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    var c = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'), d;

    for ( var x = 0, y = c.length; x < y; x++) {

        if (c[x].attributes[1].value.toLowerCase() == "og:description") {

            d = c[x];

        }

    }

    $("#maincontent_social_bar").replaceWith('<div id="maincontent_social_bar"><iframe src="http://share.bimbim.nl/sharepanel.php?s=YTozOntzOjE6ImQiO2k6MjtzOjI6InNuIjtzOjk6IjUsMSw0LDIsMyI7czoxOiJoIjtzOjMyOiI5ODdlNjAxMmYyYTU1MmY0YWQwMjdlMTY3NTFkZDIxYyI7fQ==&u='

                    + encodeURIComponent(window.location)

                    + '&t='

                    + encodeURIComponent(document.title)

                    + '&desc='

                    + encodeURIComponent(d.content)

                    + '" height="16" width="90" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:16px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>');

});

</script>
```

In google chrome it says: D is undefined. I cannot figure out Why... Can someone give me a hint?

--- UPDATE ---

Here is the HTML Header that the script is looking at:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="De landelijke docentendag voor mbo-interieurdocenten (niveau 4) op dinsdag 11 september was een succes. Ruim 30 docenten van twaalf convenantscholen waren op initiatief van WoonWerk in Nieuwegein bijeen om kennis te maken met de nieuwste ontwikkelingen in de woonbranche en te sparren met..." /><meta property="og:title" content="Grote opkomst docentendag: Onderwijs ontmoet woonbranche" /><meta name="description" content="De landelijke docentendag voor mbo-interieurdocenten (niveau 4) op dinsdag 11 september was een succes. Ruim 30 docenten van twaalf convenantscholen waren op initiatief van WoonWerk in Nieuwegein bijeen om kennis te maken met de nieuwste ontwikkelingen in de woonbranche en te sparren met..." /><meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
```

Comment: I assume that "og:description" doesn't have the attribute index [1] in Chrome so it will never be found

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the HTML you want to extract values from?

Comment: I will update the question to give the HTML...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is coming from this line:

```
encodeURIComponent(d.content)
```

If `d` is undefined at that point, it means that it didn't get assigned a value during the earlier `for` loop. This would mean that it didn't find any tags with the `"og:description"` attribute value to assign to `d`. If I were you, I would put a breakpoint after the `for` loop and check `d`'s value at that point.

Comment: This looks like the culprit, however I'd expect an error more like 'Cannot read property 'content' of undefined' in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `, d` from `var c = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'), d;`

Like this:

```
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
```

Comment: why should this make any difference? It would only make d global but it will not change the way it will be assigned with a value ...